# Pandas: Number of rows with missing data

Tags: pandas

How do I find out the total number of rows that have missing data in a Pandas DataFrame?
I have tried this:

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

But this is for the total missing fields.
I need to know how many rows are affected.

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame and expected output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html). This will return `True` if any element is `True` and `False` otherwise.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, np.nan, 1], 'b': [np.nan, np.nan, 'c']})
print(df)
```

outputs

```
     a    b
0  0.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  1.0    c
```

and

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1).sum()  # returns 2
```